How to read out a whole struct over CoE with TwinCAT?
I'm trying to read out the Resistor Measurement Settings from a EL3356 over Can over Ethernet (CoE). I'm using the FB_EcCoeSdoReadEx function block for this.
Then I want to use the bCompleteAccess to read out the whole Resistor Measurement Settings at once instead of going through all the individual parameters. For this I defined the following struct
TYPE RMB_Config : STRUCT
    MaxSubIndex : USINT; (* Max. subindex, RO, default: 50dec *)
    Mode0EnableFilter : BIT; (* 0: No filters active, 1: Filters active, RW, default: TRUE *)
    Mode1EnableFilter : BIT; (* Applies only to EL3356-0010, EL3356-0090, RW, default: TRUE *)
    Mode0EnableAverager : BIT; (* Activate hardware mean value filter, RW, default: TRUE *)
    Mode1EnableAverager : BIT; (* Applies only to EL3356-0010, EL3356-0090, RW, default: TRUE *)
    SymmetricReference : BIT; (* Activate symmetric measurement, RW, default: TRUE *)
    Mode0FilterSettings : UINT; (* Filter settings for mode 0, RW, default: 0 *)
    Mode1FilterSettings : UINT; (* Filter settings for mode 1, applies only to EL3356-0010, EL3356-0090, RW, default: 0 *)
    DynamicFilterChangeTime :
        UINT; (* Sampling rate for dynamic filter switching, RW, default: 10dec *)
    DynamicFilterDelta : REAL; (* Limit value for dynamic filter switching, RW, default: 20.0 *)
    Gain : REAL; (* Scale factor, RW, default: 1.0 *)
    Tare : REAL; (* Process data value offset, RW, default: 0.0 *)
    RatedOutput :
        REAL; (* Nominal characteristic value of the sensor element in mV/V, RW, default: 2.0 *)
    NominalLoad : REAL; (* Nominal load of the transducer, RW, default: 5.0 *)
    ZeroBalance : REAL; (* Zero point offset in mV/V, RW, default: 0.0 *)
    GravityOfEarth : REAL; (* Current acceleration of gravity, RW, default: 9.806650 *)
    ScaleFactor : REAL; (* Factor for re-scaling the process data, RW, default: 1000.0 *)
    ReferenceLoad : REAL; (* Reference weight for manual calibration, RW, default: 5.0 *)
    SteadyStateWindow : UINT; (* Time constant for "steady state" bit, RW, default: 1000dec *)
    SteadyStateTolerance : UDINT; (* Tolerance window for "steady state" bit, RW, default: 5dec *)
    CalibrationInterval :
        UINT; (* Calibration interval for automatic calibration, RW, default: 1800dec *)
    TestInterval : UINT; (* Test interval for the cyclic self-test, RW, default: 10dec *)
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

Then I try to read it using this code
PROGRAM CoEReaderTest
VAR
    coeReader : FB_EcCoeSdoReadEx;
    rmbSettings : RMB_Config;
    starting_index : BYTE := 16#0;
    execute : BOOL;
END_VAR

coeReader(
    sNetId:=Config.netId,
    nSlaveAddr:=1009,
    nIndex:=16#8000,
    nSubIndex:=starting_index,
    pDstBuf:=ADR(rmbSettings),
    cbBufLen:=SIZEOF(rmbSettings),
    bExecute:=execute,
    bCompleteAccess:=TRUE
);

The MaxSubIndex is read out correctly, but starting from the next parameter the bits do not seem to line up anymore. All other numbers are then not correct.
What I've tried to do is to us {attribute 'pack_mode':= '0'} with all different pack modes: 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, but none of them seem to align the struct correctly. Also, I replaced the BIT's with BOOL's, but that didn't solve it either.
Any ideas on how to solve this? I couldn't find examples where bCompleteAccess is used.

Do you have to define this struct yourself, manually? Sometimes, there's a struct definition you can just re-use...

Where can I find this @Guillius?

Did you tr, setting 2nd and 3d parameters to trur and false and reading it out? It could give you a clue as to what is happening. Never used the CoE read, so I cant offer any valuable input.

By looking at EL3356 configuration, could there be some padding bytes required for example between SymmetricReference and Mode0FilterSettings? As the subindex changes from 5 to 11. However that doesn't explain why the second variable is already read wrong. I have never read many variables at once, but actualy it could be useful for one case which is now reading many variables one-by-one. Need to investigate it further. What happens if you comment out MaxSubIndex and try to read from subIndex 1->?

@ziga I didn't try that yet, I mainly played around with pack modes and changing the BITs to BOOLs.

@Quirzo thanks for the tips, I'll have alook at it

If you have byte alignment issues, try adding the pack_mode attribute at the top of your structure declaration, like this :
{attribute 'pack_mode' := '0'}
TYPE RMB_Config : STRUCT
...


I think OP already tried this...

I tried that already and it didn’t  work. Or maybe I forgot a combination. Do you have a systematic way to determine what the aligned should be?

The "systematic" way is to (1) make sure you know what you are supposed to read/write, your device's documentation should have a bit-perfect description of the data and (2) understand what byte-alignment means, what the pack modes mean, and the mapping to the data to be read/written will become obvious.

Are you really, 100% sure that your structure matches the actual data?  If, say, you have a variable defined as a 2-byte type while in the real data it is single-byte, this shifts everything that follows.

When dealing with I/O devices, pack mode 0 is usually the right one. In most cases, if there are unused bits (common) or bytes (less common) in your data structure, you are better off using pack mode 0 and including this unused data explicitly (i.e. adding "unused_1, unused_2" in your structure rather than relying on pack mode to add the padding for you. Automation tends to use "weird" byte alignment (i.e. multi-byte value starting at an odd byte offset), and using pack mode 0 removes a layer of surprises.

Thanks for the useful tips. I'll try again with these in mind.
